# What does the "n" key do in vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

In normal mode, whenever I press the key **n** (single **n** or combinations with the key **n**, like **nd**, **,nn**, **jn**, etc.), the vim will show me the result of running command **:/final**.

I can't remember if I've done such mappings unconsciously or pressed some specific key combinations by mistake.

Comment: fwiw, you don't have to type `:` before search terms, you can just type `/final` while in normal mode to search

Answer (score 6):

[`n` is a default mapping in vim](https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html). In particular, `n` repeats the last search from the cursor's position down. You recently searched for "final" so that's what it searched for.

In general, it is pretty easy to find out what a key does with `:help <key>` while in vim.

In this case, that would give you

```
n                   Repeat the latest "/" or "?" [count] times.
                    If the cursor doesn't move the search is repeated with
                    count + 1.
                    |last-pattern| {Vi: no count}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm supposed to walk through vim tutorial before asking such questions.